# AngularJS: dataTransfer not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

I'm coding a simple app using AngularJS (**newbie here!**).

This app creates a list and allows you to move elements around, into diferent boxes.

The drag and drop handling worked great when using pure Javascript on the global object. But when trying to achieve the same using directives it seems the dataTransfer object of the event 'dissapears'. Here is my directive (just for a matter of testing I replaced "ondragstart" with "click"):

```
FulboApp.directive('insertPlayers',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template:'<img class="img-thumbnail" draggable="true" src="img/horangel.jpg" id="{{play.id}}" ng-dblclick="deletePlayer(play.id)" />',
        replace:true,
        link: function($scope,element,attrs){
            $(element).on('click',function(ev){

                //returns 'undefined'
                console.log(ev.dataTransfer);


                //ev.dataTransfer.setData('text',ev.target.id);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I tried using 'addEventListener', 'on', 'bind' and same happens
What am I missing?

Is there a better overall approach to what I'm trying to do?

**Edit:**

All of the angular code, therefore, all of the Javascript is placed within

```
(function(){
  ...
   //Here
  ...
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dragstart` event (not `ondragstart` unless you are binding event via attribute) in order to receive appropriate event with `dataTransfer` property. For example `click` event is not same as `dragstart` event in terms of what the event object represents. try:

```
 element.on('dragstart', function(ev) {
    //....
 });
```

Basic Demo

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('insertPlayers', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<img class="img-thumbnail" draggable="true" src="http://placehold.it/32x32" id="asdf" ng-dblclick="deletePlayer(play.id)" />',
    replace: true,
    link: function($scope, tElm) {
      tElm.on('dragstart', function dragstart(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
      });
    }
  }
}).directive('droppable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, tElm) {
      tElm.on('dragover', function dragover(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      });

      tElm.on('drop', function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <insert-players></insert-players>

  <droppable id="div1"></droppable>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, same problem, and in the example above and while testing I replaced it with 'click' and still the same. dataTransfer is undefined

Comment: @user1869935 I can see it in chrome. Which browser are you testing this with. Just to clarify once again it is not `ondragstart`

Comment: Chrome as well. Correct, I used 'dragstart'. I will add some clarification in the main text, that maybe has to do. Please, read in a minute again

Comment: @user1869935 Added a demo in the answer as well.